# String.search("|") symbol result

Tags: javascript

This is my code:

```
var sQuestionPropositionText = new String("This is a test|A");
for(var i=0; i < sQuestionPropositionText.length; i++){
console.log(sQuestionPropositionText[i] + " search result= " + sQuestionPropositionText[i].search("|"));
}
```

And this is what I got in the console:

```
T search result= 0
h search result= 0
i search result= 0
s search result= 0
  search result= 0
i search result= 0
s search result= 0
  search result= 0
a search result= 0
  search result= 0
t search result= 0
e search result= 0
s search result= 0
t search result= 0
| search result= 0
A search result= 0
```

Anyone knows why the "|" character is not found ?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Try escaping it. `\|`.

Comment: Escaping it like you said doesn't work, at least not in my case, the solution given by @t-j-crowder is the correct one (but using IndexOf was much easier)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`String#search` expects a *regular expression*. If you give it a string, it converts it to a regex via `new RegExp`. `|` is special in regular expressions.

To search for a literal character or substring, use `indexOf`. You don't need a loop:

```
var sQuestionPropositionText = "This is a test|A";
var foundAt = sQuestionPropositionText.indexOf("|"); // 14
```

Or of course, you could escape it, but it's awkward in string form because `\` is both the escape character in string literals *and* the escape character in regular expressions, so to put a `\` in the regex to escape the `|`, you need *two* in the string literal (the first to escape the second):

```
var sQuestionPropositionText = "This is a test|A";
var foundAt = sQuestionPropositionText.search("\\|"); // 14
```

If you're going to use `search`, usually best to pass it a regex, not a string:

```
var sQuestionPropositionText = "This is a test|A";
var foundAt = sQuestionPropositionText.search(/\|/); // 14
```

---

Side note: There are virtually no situations in which `new String` is useful in JavaScript, which is why I removed it above.